# What exactly IS the parameter to the EFFECT itself in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

still battling with `useEffect`. 

I read a few things and thought i got a grasp on the dependencies array at the end, but apparently not.

Say, i have this:

```
const StructRequestable = ({ struct, state, requestDataMap }) => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      console.log("Redux state is", state);
    },
    [state]
  );
  return (
<div> Soggy pasta</div>
)}


...


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return  {
    state: state
  }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(StructRequestable);
```

And I expect this to work as a logger for the `state` changes and nothing else and it does!
Now, why the hell doesn't this(below) work and what is the difference? I would think the version below correct, but apparently adding this parameter changes the inner one? Does it have to do with scope of the effect? Thanks for any tips!

```
const StructRequestable = ({ struct, state, requestDataMap }) => {
  useEffect(
    (state) => {                                 // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ADDED STATE HERE. NOTHING ELSE.
      console.log("Redux state is", state);
    },
    [state]
  );
  return (
<div> Soggy pasta</div>
)}


...


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return  {
    state: state
  }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(StructRequestable);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [variable shadowing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), and this is more of a general programming concept so nothing to do with hooks or `useEffect` behaviour. If you have a variable named in the inner most scope it will override any outer scope variables with the same name.

The `useEffect` callback doesn't take a parameter therefore `state` in your log I presume would show as `undefined`.